# Двоеточие, запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Вижу для следующего предложения три, если не четыре варианта расстановки знаков препинания. Мозг очень устал, сам правила толком не обрабатывает.

**"Я взял все необходимое для нашей встречи(:) ружье и патроны";**
**"Я взял все необходимое для нашей встречи(,) ружье и патроны";**
**"Я взял все необходимое для нашей встречи (—) ружье и патроны".**

В качестве четвертого варианта я рассматривала сочетание запятой и тире, но это, по-поему, уже совсем неверно и свидетельствует о том, что у кого-то ум за разум заехал.

Пожалуйста, поясните, какой из этих вариантов предпочтительней и почему, какой совсем невозможен или выглядит наименее уместным, является ли в данном случае постановка всех трех знаков вариативной или нет? За ссылку на конкретное правило — отдельная благодарность.
Всем заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Все необходимое" - обобщаюшие слова перед перечислением однородных членов (ружье и патроны). По Розенталю, после них может идти двоеточие или тире. Если стоит запятая, то "ружье и патроны" могут рассматриваться как приложение, имеющее пояснительный характер. Но этот вариант кажется мне неудачным.

Answer (score 0):

Я взял все необходимое для нашей встречи: ружье и патроны

Я взял все необходимое для нашей встречи,ружье и патроны

Я взял все необходимое для нашей встречи — ружье и патроны

Подробно о знаках препинания при однородных членах можете ознакомиться здесь: [Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)

Comment: По-моему, в случае с запятой у нас приложение, которое имеет  пояснительный характер, а не однородные члены. Не исключено, что в случае с тире - тоже.

Comment: Где вы видите БСП? Просто обобщающее слово перед перечислением однородных членов предложения.

Comment: МГ, да, вы правы, спутал.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы считаете ружье и патроны единственным, что Вам нужно, то лучше ставить не тире, а двоеточие. Двоеточие проверяется и употребляется после понижения голоса. Тире - после повышения. Например,  необходимое для нашей встречи - любовь и ласка. Слышится повышение интонации перед тире.
 Перечисление же  разного необходимого, а потом инвентаря для стрельбы не вызвало бы у Вас вопрос по запятым.